# How can i execute a sql server 2008 command by a batch file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, batch-file

i have to execute a sql command from a batch file. like :-

"Select top 1 versionNumber from SchemaVersion order by Id desc"

and Show its result on batch file , just when this batch file gets open.

please can any one suggest me right solution to do this ??

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the sqlcmd.exe command in your batch file. (MSDN Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)

```
sqlcmd.exe -S mysqlserver -d mydb -U myuser -P mypass -Q "Select top 1 versionNumber from SchemaVersion order by Id desc"
```

for example

Comment: thanks for your useful reply, but can i do it without giving USERID and PASSWORD,

Comment: If you leave out user and password it will automatically attempt to use Windows authentication.

Comment: It should just output to the console if you don't specify a file to output to with the `-o` option.

Comment: yes the query result exactly the same i need, but it is also giving a big horizontal line and a message "<1 row effected>" , with the output. i want to remove all this and just need a number, how can i do this ?

Comment: You'll have to add `set nocount on;` to the beginning of the query

Comment: thanks again for your suggestions, really very helpful, well by applying set nocount on; i found "<1 row affected>" has been removed but, i am still getting ------------------------ this type of dashed line in output , so what can i do to remove this line,

Answer (score 1):

specify -Q "set nocount on;  Select top 1 versionNumber from SchemaVersion order by Id desc"